# Pathing for pipe style layout

Tags: path-finding

I've been trying to think of ways to approach doing a pipe style game like the one pictured below, but am coming up short.

The pic is from Star Trek Elite Force 2, the hacking minigame part. I've never played the game, but found this particular part via a search.

[image]

The player must click on to turn each pipe section and get a path between the blue nodes, while not connecting to any red nodes.

I assumed the way to create the pipe route is to begin from the end node and generate a path towards the starting node, then obscure the path with branches. But on trying this, the path is very obvious (pic added below), so I'm looking for other ideas.

Does anyone have any pointers to set me in the right direction?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of the kind of output you're generating now?

Comment: Sure, have done. Ignore the rotations, was just checking the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we can use a technique Squirrel Eiserloh calls "Perlin Routes" to get a more meandering, less obvious initial path.

Assign a random cost to every edge between two cells in your grid. You can do this either in a pre-process, or use a hash/noise function that maps an edge location to a (consistent) pseudorandom cost on demand. Using a 2D noise function with a few octaves gives you control over how many big detours you get, and how many smaller wiggles along the way.

Now run A* between your start and goal tiles, using these traversal costs. Sometimes there will be high cost wall blocking the most direct path, forcing A* to detour around it. The result is a more organic-looking, zig-zaggy path that can sometimes make U-turns or other deviations to obfuscate its aim. Mark the cells crossed by this path as part of the solution.

Now re-randomize your costs (or shift your noise/hash seed), and do it again. You'll get another chaotic path. Mark any cells it crosses that aren't already on the main path "decoy" cells.

Repeat as many times as you like to create your desired density of decoy paths. If you're using a noise function, you can choose to re-randomize only the higher octaves, leaving the base octave unchanged, so that your decoy paths mostly follow the same broad arc as the main path, but differ in the details.

Next we can add some elaboration. Look through all the empty cells that are adjacent to either a solution cell or a decoy cell, and mark some of them as decoys with some probability. Maybe higher if they're touching multiple decoy cells, lower if they're touching just one (dead ends).

Repeat that step as many times as you like to fuzz-out the paths with distractions.

Now you can go assign actual tile shapes to each tile. First, do the solution tiles, initially giving them the shape that matches the solution path through that tile. Then you can add side branches to them with some probability (eg. turning a corner or straightaway into a 3-way junction), as long as that addition doesn't connect them to a hazard.

You can do the same with your decoy paths, but periodically insert a random tile shape instead so it's not guaranteed to actually connect. Just test that doing this does not inadvertently connect a hazard to the solution path.

The remaining decoy tiles you can fill randomly, again subject to the constraint that they should not connect the solution path to a hazard.

Lastly, randomly rotate all of the tiles and verify that the start and goal are not connected.

Approaching it this way, you can get alternative solutions (multiple orientations of the solution tiles that work, or ways to use "decoy" tiles to shortcut the solution), but for many styles of puzzle this is a positive feature. And you can guarantee that even without these coincidental solutions, your puzzle will have at least one valid solution.